# How to get adb working in user build recovery?

Tags: android, adb, boot, recovery, selinux

I have Tecno Spark 10 pro. It has recovery ramdisk as boot. It has initboot vendorboot partitions but they are all not in use (written with 0s)

I can modify the ramdisk and change the build prop for adb not to be secure to be 0 or put adb keys to /adb_keys in both cases running adb shell gives out the following

```
could not set selinux context for subprocess libc
```

How do I get adb to work?